# how to check if logged in previosly in android app

Tags: android, loopback

i am working on android application, usually when we use different app then they requires only one time user login, and when we use next time then it does not require to login again, just like Facebook ,gmail etc

i also want to have such a functionality, so that it should save the username and password in shared preference, and i am using strong loop-back API(strong loop-back is basic requirement) following code i have just written it, but i want to use Access Token for it, can have give me the idea that how to use loop-back Access Token in android...???

```
 public boolean checkLogin() {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
            this.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String userName = prefs.getString("userName", "");
    if (userName.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i("UserName", "UserName not found.");
        return false;
    }

    String password = prefs.getString("password", "");
    if (password.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i("Password", "Password not found.");
        return false;
    }


    mCheckTask = new CheckSavedLogin(userName, password, this);
    mCheckTask.execute((Void) null);


    return mCheckTask.execute((Void) null);//make this return true/false
}
```

and also:

```
 public class CheckSavedLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    public final String mUserName;
    public final String mPassword;
    public boolean success;
    public Context context;

    CheckSavedLogin(String userName, String password, Context context) {
        mUserName = userName;
        mPassword = password;
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://173.242.94.66/scripts/appLogin.php");

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", mUserName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseStr);
            success = json.getBoolean("success");

            Log.d("Response", responseStr);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return success;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            storeLoginDetails(mUserName, mPassword);
            //RETURN TRUE HERE?
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set your shared preference to public and other applications can read from it. But its not recommended. I would go for exported AccountAuthenticator.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but i want to use Access token using string loop-back API, can you please give any guess that how can i use it in android?